# Sumar totales en django template

Tags: python, django

Estoy realizando un proyecto en Django y tengo un problema al sumar el total de una de las columnas de mi consulta. La consulta cuenta todos los dias que un usuario ha utilizado el servicio en un mes y los multiplica por la quota que esta en otro modelo. Con el filtro mathfilters pude multiplicar la quota con cada iteracion de la lista de usuarios. Pero no se como puedo realizar el sumatorio total de los recibos del mes. Entiendo que la solucion seria en el view definir una funcion para calcular cada recibo y finalmente el total de todos los recibos... Pero no se como hacer una funcion que trabaje con los valores extraidos de una query.

Alguna ayuda? Gracias!

**View.py**

```
class InformeMensual(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    login_url = "/admin/login/"
    redirect_field_name = "next"
    template_name ='estones/estones_informe.html'
    context_object_name = 'usuaris'
    model = EstonesDia

def get_queryset(self):
    self.value_mes = self.request.GET.get('mes', '0')
    return EstonesDia.objects.filter(data__month=self.value_mes).values('id_usuari__usuari_nom', 'id_usuari__usuari_curs').annotate(dies=Count('id_usuari__usuari_nom'))

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(InformeMensual, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['quota'] = EstonesQuotes.objects.all().first()
    context['mes'] = self.value_mes
    return context
```

**template.html:**

```
  {% for item in object_list %}
      <tr>
           <td>{{ item.id_usuari__usuari_nom }}</td>
           <td>{{ item.id_usuari__usuari_curs }}</td>
           <td>{{ item.dies }}</td>                                
           <td>{{ item.dies|mul:2.5 }}</td>
      </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```